# Spring Boot not serving static javascript file

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a very strange behaviour of Spring Boot application (1.4.0.RELEASE)

My static content lies under `/src/main/resources/static/*` and one of the pages needs css and js files, but despite the fact that css files are served without problems I am getting 404 for js files:

For CSS file I see in the logs

```
SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : No handler mapping found for [/admin_files/custom_admin.css]
RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /admin_files/custom_admin.css
RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/admin_files/custom_admin.css]
SimpleUrlHandlerMapping: Matching patterns for request [/admin_files/custom_admin.css] are [/**]
SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/admin_files/custom_admin.css] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/], (...)
```

so it looks completely fine. However for JS file it looks different:

```
SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : No handler mapping found for [/admin_files/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js]
RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/admin_files/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js]
SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/admin_files/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js] are [/**]
SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/admin_files/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/] (...)
//
// and now something strange starts to happen BELOW
//
HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Written [{timestamp=Tue Sep 13 23:17:12 CEST 2016, status=404, error=Not Found, message=No message available, path=/admin_files/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js}] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@29139aae]
```

I am really stuck as it looks like a very small glitch or something very tiny that I am missing somewhere.

My application looks like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableEncryptableProperties
public class Application extends WicketBootSecuredWebApplication { }
```

without any custom configuration beans, etc.

`tree` executed in `/src/main/resources`:

```
.
├── application-dev.yml
├── application-prod.yml
├── application-staging.yml
├── application.yml
├── banner.txt
└── static
    └── admin_files
        ├── custom_admin.css
        └── vendor
            ├── jquery
            │   ├── jquery.js
            │   └── jquery.min.js
            └── metisMenu
                ├── metisMenu.css
                ├── metisMenu.js
                ├── metisMenu.min.css
                └── metisMenu.min.js
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Did you configure `mvc` options or left it to autoconfiguration?

Comment: @nurgasemetey No `mvc` related configuration in my yaml files.

Comment: Please add the porject/resource tree

Comment: @reos Done, `tree` output added. But something would be messed with placing static files in a proper directory, both css and js files wouldn't be served properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you're asking for /admin_files/vendor/jquery/**dist**/jquery.min.js but in your resource tree the **dist** directory does not exist.